# Symbology for Open Street Map [OSM] Data in MapInfo [tab] format

Tags: openstreetmap, mapinfo, symbology, tab

I have shapefiles for the different OSM layers which I have translated into TABs but I am now trying to symbolise them in a similar style to OSM online.

Is there a way to easily apply the OSM symbology to MapInfo TAB files?

Answer (score 1):

**MapInfo To QGIS Style Generator**

Note: @Nathanw (GIS-SE user, QGIS Dev) would probably give you a more complete answer

He has written  python  code to do this:

Here is a quick run though on how to use the MapInfo to QGIS style generator.

> Preparing the file from MapInfo
>
> Open MapInfo and open the table that you wish to generate the QGIS
>   style for.
>
> Run the following commands in the MapBasic windows, replacing anything
>   in {} with your info
>
> Select {Your value column}, Str$(ObjectInfo(obj,2)) from {Your Table}
>   Where Str$(ObjectInfo(obj,1)) = "5" Group By {Your value column} Into
>   outputTable
>
> Export "outputTable" Into "{Your output file}.txt" Type "ASCII"
>   Delimiter "|" CharSet "WindowsLatin1"
>
> Follow the instructions below or usage guide to generate QML file.

'mapinfoToQgis.py'

http://nathanw.net/2011/08/08/new-tool-mapinfo-to-qgis-style-converter/

Instructions & Source Code:
https://github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator/wiki/Using-MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator.
https://github.com/NathanW2/MapInfo-to-QGIS-style-generator

Comment: Thanks for the response but unfortunately I don't have access to QGIS (yet) and I'm only looking to symbolise the OSM data within MapInfo to a similar style to that used at openstreetmap.org. Also I can't see how transferring my data into QGIS will help me complete my request? Please could you explain further? Thanks BobJim

Comment: Don't have access (an IT thing?) you can download it here http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html (if cannot install?) then a USB version (QGIS 1.8) can be used from a USB Stick http://cyclatron.users.sourceforge.net/menuitem-howto-soft-alterations/7-article-howto-softalteration-qgisportable-1-8

Comment: In terms of QGIS, I'll definitely be creating a portable version from my home copy of QGIS. Perhaps this will start the open source ball rolling! Is there no where on the internet which details the symbology styles used to re-create the OSM symbology? E.g. RGB values etc etc?